# How to substract time(hours,minute,seconds,miliseconds) from given unix timstamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I have following timstamp : `1485410296976`
I want following timstamp: `1485369000000`

How do i achive this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just the Math the sh*t out of it.

```
function toMs(h, m, s, ms) {
  return (h * 3600000) + (m * 60000) + (s * 1000) + m;
}

function subtractTime(t, h, m, s, ms) {
  return t - toMs(h, m, s, ms);
}

subtractTime(1485410296976, 1, 15, 20, 700);
```

Comment: You mentioned `hours`, `seconds` and `milliseconds`. Wonder why you missed `minutes`. If that is your use case please pass `m` as 0.

Comment: Thanx @Aditya, How could you pass `1,5,20,700` in `subtractTime` parameter ?